# AWSMobileClient is not found

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-hub

I`ve followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) steps to add the AWS Mobile SDK to my app.
When I reach step 4 of the "Connect your backend" section and try to compile my app I get the following error:

```
Error:(20, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable AWSMobileClient
```

I've looked up the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/) and found that the `AWSMobileClient` class should be inside the `com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient` package, but when I try to manually import the mentioned package, I get the following error:

```
Error:(9, 28) error: package com.amazonaws.mobile does not exist
```

My current project files look like these:

MainActivity.java

```
package point.cursoandroid.com.medpoint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button botaoLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();
        botaoLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoLoginId);

        botaoLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "point.cursoandroid.com.medpoint"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.6.+'
}
```

Using AndroidStudio 3.0.1
So, any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import the appropriate dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.+@aar') { transitive = true; }
}
```

Perform a gradle sync and you should be able to import the class and package.

EDIT: Replace `2.16.+` with the latest version of the AWS SDK for Android. The latest version can be found either in [GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/releases) or [Maven Repository](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client).

More information about `AWSMobileClient` can be found in the [Documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication) and [APIReference](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/mobile/client/package-summary.html).

Comment: Thank you. Where were you able to find this info?

Comment: It's in step (3) of the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#connect-to-your-backend.

Comment: The initialize method when called with the context (this), initializes the SDK , fetches the cognito identity. This will give you access to the AWSConfiguration object and the AWSCredentialsProvider object that you can use to instantiate other clients offered by the SDK. When the execute() succeeds, you will be able to access the credentials provider object through AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider().

Comment: Its in Get Started guide -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Comment: @ShubhamGoel Are you still getting "cannot find symbol variable AWSMobileClient" even after importing the dependency?

Comment: Can you try `implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.9.+@aar') { transitive = true; }`

Comment: compile is depreciated in the latest versions.