# Amazon S3 issues - Cannot resolve symbol AmazonS3Client

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I'm trying to integrate Amazon S3 into my app.

I followed the following document, and added the corresponding dependencies:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html

When I'm trying to integrate the "Upload a File" section into my app, I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol AmazonS3Client".
This should be the import:

```
import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
```

However, for some reason, this is what I see in my code:
[image]

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Did you add the dependencies ? If yes , try to resync once

Comment: Already tried that. :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, this issue solves it (the document I was following did not include the needed 3rd import):

[AWSMobileClient is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724113/awsmobileclient-is-not-found)